# Automatically adjusting font size in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, font-size

This is my first question on the website, so let me know if it should be more detailed or asked differently.

I am using python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.0.0

Basically I am doing a matplotib bar chart and I want to have the y values above or in the bar. This is a recurrent question, and using all previous answers I have been able to write an 'autolabel' function that works pretty well. However there is one issue I cannot manage to solve. This graph is part of a big report that is automatically generated, and the time frame can change. So it could be for a week, a month or a year. So I could have a few bars only like a few hundred of them. 
when I save the fig as a png, in order to be able to zoom in an read everything I need, I used a fig size of 15*15 and dpi=1200.

So my issue is that depending on the numbers of bars, the width of the bars change and so should the font size. I managed to have it worked pretty with 22 days, but it does not adapt when I change the dates, even though my font size is a function of the number of days (thus numbers of bars). I'll give the code where I plot the bars, and the autolabel function. The project is big and I cannot put the entire code, so let me know if you need more informations. I cal the auto label function for one rect only, but eventually I will do it for all once it works.

```
fig2, (ax21, ax22) =plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
fig2.set_size_inches(15, 15)
ind2=ind.tolist()


### Stuffs with the first subplots###

width=0.1
rects21=ax22.bar(ind-3*width, TotDelta, color='#620DB7', width=width, align='center', label='Actual Delta')
check.autolabel(rects21, ax22, width) ### THE AUTOLABEL FUNCTION
rects22=ax22.bar(ind-2*width, delta, color='r',width=width, align='center', label='Model Delta')
rects23=ax22.bar(ind-width, DeltaExp, color='c', width=width, align='center', label='Delta Explained')
rects24=ax22.bar(ind, fees, color='b', width=width, align='center', label='Fees')
rects25=ax22.bar(ind+width, slip, color='#F0F304', width=width, align='center', label='Slippage')
rects26=ax3.bar(ind+2*width, other, color='g', width=width, align='center', label='Other Unamtched')
rects27=ax3.bar(ind+3*width, unexp, color='#692C2C', width=width, align='center', label='Unexplained Delta')
ax22.axhline(linewidth=1, color='k')
ax22.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(check.date_format))
ax22.grid()
fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('small')
ax22.legend(loc='center left', prop=fontP, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
fig2.tight_layout()
fig2.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, right=0.85)
fig2.suptitle('All Trades')
fig2.savefig("/Users/davidabitbol/Documents/all_dollar.png", dpi=1200)
```

The Auto Label Function:

```
def autolabel(rects, ax, width):
#To be used with a 15*15 fig size and 1200 dpi png
(y_bottom, y_top) = ax.get_ylim()
y_height = y_top - y_bottom

for rect in rects:
    height = rect.get_height()
    y=rect.get_y()
    height
    if height != 0:

        if y>=0: # Positive value, we use the height of the bar, y value = 0 for some reasons
            p_height=height/y_top

            if p_height > 0.8: #If more thna 0.8 then we write the text in the bar, as there is not enough place above or below it.
                label_position = height - (y_height * 0.05)
            else:
                label_position = height + (y_height * 0.01)

            ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., label_position,
                    '%.3f' % height,
                    ha='center', va='bottom', size=(22*width)/(10*len(rects)))

        else: # if negative we use the y value since the heing is positivie
            p_height=y/y_bottom

            if p_height > 0.8:
                label_position = y + (y_height * 0.05)
            else:
                label_position = y - (y_height * 0.01)

            ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., label_position,
            '%.3f' % y,
            ha='center', va='bottom', size=(22*width)/(10*len(rects)))
```

Comment: Anyone with an idea so the size of the text is more or less the with of the bar in the saved image?

Comment: Have you considered keeping the bar width and font size fixed while increasing or decreasing the figure width to accommodate the number of bars required? If you have to zoom in anyway to read the text size, you might as well keep the text size fixed and just scroll through your bar chart. You could zoom out to get a perspective of the full chart--just like you seem to be describing.

Comment: @Brian thanks, Sorry I just saw your comment. I was not on my computer anymore. Could you be more specific about what you're suggesting? If I understand correctly you want me to change the fig_size depending on the number of bars. The issue doing so would be that the location of the legend, title, and margins should be adapted as well...

Comment: No worries. Yes, changing the `fig_size` parameter is what I am suggesting. The location of the legend, title, and margins is normally specified in terms of the object as a whole (e.g. `bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5)` specifies the legend should be located in the center of the right-hand side on your axis regardless of absolute size).

Comment: If you would like specific assistance (as in actual code) please share a simplified and functional example of your plot with dummy data so we can reproduce the problem. See the Stack Overflow documentation for guidance: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).